# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'currency' of 'o.lb[e]' as it is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hope you are doing good! I need little help I am getting this error in the console, and I don't figure out how to resolve it.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'currency' of 'o.lb[e]' as it is undefined.

[image]

Can anyone help to fix this?

Comment: I don't see any code here to look at for problems. Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: I have the exact same issue on the exact same lines of vendors.js. Something to do with currency. Very hard to debug

Answer (score 0):

If you are using parcel, it's not about your code, it's a bug in their injected snippet for hot-reloading.